# how can i replace a function call with a new thread but pass variables to the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

this is the code i have (sort of)

```
foo(a, b)
{
    c = a.item;

    bar(c);
    b = a;
    b.count--;
}
```

i want bar(c) to run in a separate thread. 
So far this is what i have: 
i make the class implement runnable.
I replace the bar(c) line with `t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread"); t.start();`
and i create a function later in the code that looks like this:

```
public void run
{
    bar(c);
}
```

the problem is that i dont know how to get c into run. can anyone explain how i can do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code to run `bar(c)` in its own thread.

```
foo(a, b)
{
    final c = a.item;
    new Thread() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bar(c);
        }
    }.start();
    b = a;
    b.count--;
}
```

Essentially what you are doing is creating a new `Thread` object that will just make the call to `bar(c)`.  You also need to make `c` final in the method so you are allowed to pass it into the `run` method of the anonymous inner class.

I would also like to note that using this method, the `Thread` that runs `bar` just goes off on its merry way and you have no way to monitor its progress.  You may want to add some more robust logic to handle the flow of the program. (If it's needed.)

Comment: would this thread setup still terminate when the bar(c) call returned /

Comment: @Skeith, as soon as the call to `bar(c)`  terminates, the new `Thread` will also terminate.

Comment: @Skeith, also, the main thread will terminate even if the call to `bar(c)` has not.

Comment: while using your code at compile i am told that i am not overriding abstract method run, what have i done wrong ?

Comment: @Skeith, I do not get an error.  (There is a warning because I left off the `@Override` annotation.  I made a slight change to the code to fix that.)

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of Runnable that takes a value in its constructor. Run the Runnable in the thread.